# SwiftUI: How to add methods in custom view behaving like built-in modifiers?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Sometimes when custom a view in SwiftUI, it require some parameters to change the appearance of it which is not possible to be achieve by `ViewModifier`. Like the demo shown below, I want to set text color and image color separately.

```
struct CustomView: View {
    
    var imageColor: Color
    var textColor: Color
    
    init(imageColor: Color = .primary, textColor: Color = .primary) {
        self.imageColor = imageColor
        self.textColor = textColor
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "star")
                .foregroundColor(imageColor)
            Text("Hello World")
                .foregroundColor(textColor)
        }
    }
}
```

Though providing parameters via `init()` works. But it's ugly when there're tens of parameters. It could be a nightmare to invoke it.

SwiftUI uses modifiers to solve this problem. It couldn't be better if I can custom my own.

#### Solution1 (but not working)

```
struct CustomView: View {
    
    var imageColor: Color = .primary
    var textColor: Color = .primary
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "star")
                .foregroundColor(imageColor)
            Text("Hello World")
                .foregroundColor(textColor)
        }
    }
    
    mutating func imageColor(_ imageColor: Color) -> CustomView {
        self.imageColor = imageColor
        return self
    }
    
    mutating func textColor(_ textColor: Color) -> CustomView {
        self.textColor = textColor
        return self
    }
}
```

But there's an error when compiling `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value`.

```
CustomView()
    .imageColor(.red)    // error
    .textColor(.blue)    // error
```

Then I changed the `var` to `@State var` in `CustomView` struct. But the value will never change when calling it. The reason I found is discussed here: https://forums.swift.org/t/im-so-confused-why-state-var-inside-a-view-do-not-change-when-you-call-a-method-on-this-view-from-some-outer-view/31944

#### Solution2 (but inefficient)

```
struct CustomView: View {
    
    var imageColor: Color
    var textColor: Color
    
    init(imageColor: Color = .primary, textColor: Color = .primary) {
        self.imageColor = imageColor
        self.textColor = textColor
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "star")
                .foregroundColor(imageColor)
            Text("Hello World")
                .foregroundColor(textColor)
        }
    }

    func imageColor(_ imageColor: Color) -> CustomView {
        return CustomView(imageColor: imageColor, textColor: self.textColor)
    }

    func textColor(_ textColor: Color) -> CustomView {
        return CustomView(imageColor: self.imageColor, textColor: textColor)
    }
}
```

Obviously, it takes a little more system resource as shown in below monitor of Xcode. So how can I add modifiers like these efficiently? How Apple SwifUI's built-in modifiers made this?
[image: Memory-use monitored by Xcode]

Comment: the best and simplest approach will be to use @State wrapper before var then you don't have to have mutable

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali I can't make the `@State` work. The actual value will never change. The reason are described here: https://forums.swift.org/t/im-so-confused-why-state-var-inside-a-view-do-not-change-when-you-call-a-method-on-this-view-from-some-outer-view/31944

Comment: I struggle with exactly the same issue. Did you find anything in the mean time?

Comment: @Gregor One solution I'm using is to define a custom `EnvironmentKey` and extension it in `EnvironmentValues`, then set that environment value inside modifier-like functions like `environment(\.customEnvironment, value)`. But it's not ideal, since the environment value will affect the child views.

Comment: Thanks @YimingDesigner. I already have your solution as a workaround. Even with a function that sets the environment. The only thing missing is that the function has to return "some View". Would it be possible to return the custom View itself it would have been much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation here. I have a padding inside the CustomView that I would like to change via a specific modifier, and the following seemed to work in my case (changed the wording to work with your example):

```
extension CustomView {
    func imageColor(_ imageColor: Color) -> CustomView {
        var newView = self
        self.imageColor = imageColor
        return newView
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
CustomView()
    .imageColor(.red)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

To build your own view modifier, you first need to define a `struct` that conforms to `ViewModifier`, e.g.

```
struct ImageColor:  ViewModifier {    
    let color: Color
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .foregroundColor(color)
    }
}
```

then for ease of use at the call-site, add a view extension as follows:

```
extension View where Self == Image {
    func imageColor(_ color: Color) -> some View {
        modifier(ImageColor(color: color))
    }
}
```

then you can use it just like a "built-in" modifier…

```
Image(systemName: "star")
    .imageColor(imageColor)
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, sometimes there are some abstractions (e.g. in a module) that I cannot access inner code of `CustomView`. So I think `ViewModifier` won't work.